# Bootstrap fixed header not working on iPad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap-affix to make a search bar fixed on scroll. It's working on the browser, however on mobile Safari it doesn't work as intended. 
It does fix to the top, but only once the user lifts of their finger when scrolling. 
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: This is a common issue with IOS and no fixed solution works unless the element starts off fixed. IOS just has problems with calculating fixed position as you scroll. Basically you don't get an updated fixed position until a slight delay after you stop scrolling, there is no fix. You can try all manner of addons, bootstrap, waypoints, and all of them, this is native behavior

Answer (score 8):

Add the following style to your element:

```
transform:translateZ(0)
```

Comment: Any more explanation on how that fixes the issue?

Comment: yep, add css style to the element like so: #element {transform:translateZ(0)};

Comment: Perfect, I added this to my .navbar and it works perfectly. Thanks scooterlord

Comment: A huge help. Thank you!

Comment: @accord_guy Glad it helped you

Comment: seven years later, still an issue but this fixed it for me